# Find a general 2x2 matrix where A = adj(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

I know how to find the adjoint of $2\times 2$ matrix but I'm at a loss for finding a general  $2\times 2$ matrix where $A = adj(A)$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

If $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ then $\operatorname{adj} A = \begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$. So you need to find $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}.
$$
In other words, you have to solve the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{align*}
a &= d, \\ b &= -b, \\ c &= -c, \\ d &= a.
\end{align*}
$$
You take it from here.